# background image is stretching too much

Tags: android

I am building an Android application. On the front page I am displaying a random background image. This means that the width and height is dynamic. The problem is that the background image is being stretched.

I am displaying it in the LinearLayout  with the code

```
android:background="@drawable/img_salad_thumb".
```

Here is a screenshot of the app:

[image: This is how my app looks]

As you can see the background image loading behind the logo is very stretched…

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayoutMain"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/img_salad_thumb"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter">

        <!-- Header -->
        <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:stretchColumns="1">

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow1">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="28dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <!-- Category -->
                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imageViewCategory"
                        android:layout_width="36dp"
                        android:layout_height="36dp"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_menu_white_24px"/>

                    <!-- Favorite -->
                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imageViewFavorite"
                        android:layout_width="36dp"
                        android:layout_height="36dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_favorite_white_24px" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <!-- Logo -->
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageViewLogoSite"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal|center"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/img_circle_96"
                    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="1dp" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="28dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <!-- Home -->
                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imageViewWebsite"
                        android:layout_width="36dp"
                        android:layout_height="36dp"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_home_white_24px"/>

                    <!-- Comment -->
                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imageViewDiscuss"
                        android:layout_width="36dp"
                        android:layout_height="36dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_question_answer_white_24px"/>
                </LinearLayout>

            </TableRow>

        </TableLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewLogoTitle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:shadowColor="#000"
            android:shadowDx="3"
            android:shadowDy="3"
            android:shadowRadius="6"
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            android:textSize="28sp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
            android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"  />
        <!-- //Header -->


        <!-- Search -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editTextSearchQuery"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_search_grey_24px"
                android:background="@drawable/edittext_activity_main_search"
                android:hint="@string/search_for_recipe"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:singleLine="false"
                android:text=""
                android:layout_weight=".60"
                android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="6dp"
                android:background="@android:color/background_light"/>

        </LinearLayout>
        <!-- //Search -->

        <!-- Recipes -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="@color/colorLightGray">

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/listViewRecipes"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:dividerHeight="1dp"></ListView>

        </LinearLayout>
        <!-- //Recipes -->




    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

because you set image in main linear layout have math_parent in both of layout_width and layout_height ... actually your image fill all the screen in background and you just see a part of it .

update your code like this

```
enter code her<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:fillViewport="true"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayoutMain"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/img_salad_thumb"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter">

        <!-- Header -->
        <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:stretchColumns="1">

            <TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow1">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="28dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <!-- Category -->
                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imageViewCategory"
                        android:layout_width="36dp"
                        android:layout_height="36dp"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_menu" />

                    <!-- Favorite -->
                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imageViewFavorite"
                        android:layout_width="36dp"
                        android:layout_height="36dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_call" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <!-- Logo -->
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageViewLogoSite"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal|center"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/img_circle_96" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginRight="28dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <!-- Home -->
                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imageViewWebsite"
                        android:layout_width="36dp"
                        android:layout_height="36dp"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_home_white_24px" />

                    <!-- Comment -->
                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imageViewDiscuss"
                        android:layout_width="36dp"
                        android:layout_height="36dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_question_answer_white_24px" />
                </LinearLayout>

            </TableRow>

        </TableLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewLogoTitle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:shadowColor="#000"
            android:shadowDx="3"
            android:shadowDy="3"
            android:shadowRadius="6"
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
            android:textSize="28sp" />
        <!-- //Header -->


        <!-- Search -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editTextSearchQuery"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
                android:layout_weight=".60"
                android:background="@drawable/edittext_activity_main_search"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_search_grey_24px"
                android:hint="@string/search_for_recipe"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:singleLine="false"
                android:text="" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="6dp"
                android:background="@android:color/background_light" />

        </LinearLayout>
        <!-- //Search -->

    </LinearLayout>


    <!-- Recipes -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorLightGray"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listViewRecipes"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:dividerHeight="1dp"></ListView>

    </LinearLayout>
    <!-- //Recipes -->


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you. I've tried so many diffrent methods, but this did the trick!

Answer (score -1):

hi，Setting the attribute 'android:scaleType' in ImageView may help you.

You can get more information about 'scaleType' here

[ImageView.ScaleType | Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html)

Comment: scaleType does not affect View.background, it only affects ImageView.src. Plus, as you can see, he already tried it.